# Smallest eigenvalue map is continous

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For my homework, I am trying to show that for a $d\times d$ matrix $A$, the map $A\mapsto\lambda_1(A)$ is continuous and where $\lambda_1(A)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ and where continuity is with respect to the max-norm on matrices. Besides trying to use the definition of continuity (which I tried), I don't really know where to start with this.

Edit:
$A$ is symmetric and $\lambda_1$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d} \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: assuming your field is $\mathbb C$ you may want to consider $A(t)=\left( \begin{matrix} 0 &1 \\t &0 \end{matrix} \right)$.  Each eigenvalue satisfies $\lambda^2(t)=t$ for all $t\in \mathbb C$ but this can't be continuous over the complex plane-- contradiciton.  (Insert winding number argument or whatever you like from complex analysis.) So you'll need to spend some time refining the notion of continuity or the structure of $A$ (e.g. perhaps it is hermitian).  I'd suggest starting by writing the domain and codomain of your "continuous map".

Comment: Oh I didn't consider that this might be a problem. I think it's implied in the exercise that the matrix is real

Comment: If your matrixes are SDP the lowest eigenvalue application is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @blamethelag Can you give me a hint for how I might show this?

Comment: Use the min/max principle